# If one column contains words of another column match

Tags: r

Let's say `A` and `B` are columns in the dataset, I want to develop a fuzzy match logic - if there is at least one word in column A that matches one word in column B except for the word "bank" and "of", we assign `1` in the new column, if there's 0 match, we assign `0`. I want to do this in R.

```
A                          B
BANK OF AMERICA         CHASE BANK
BANK OF AMERICA         BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.
BANK OF HOPE            HOPE BANK
T.D BANK                CHASE BANK
```

expected output

```
A                         B                        C
BANK OF AMERICA         CHASE BANK                 0
BANK OF AMERICA         BANK OF AMERICA, N.A       1
BANK OF HOPE            HOPE BANK                  1
T.D. BANK               CHASE BANK                 0
```

Comment: Please always provide your data as R code in your question (to help us developing possible answers quickly) + show the expected results for the example (which may be trivial in your case I guess - only the second row gets a `1` - if I also ignore the stop word "of")

Comment: yes, in my case, only the second row gets a 1. I will edit my post.

Comment: How many rows do you want to process (rough estimation)? Performance may be critical if you want to process millions of rows with the answers given so far (even though its hard to imagine you are processing so many different legal entities)...

Comment: Really not that many. About 10k rows

Comment: OK so please mark the best working answer (if any ;-) with a green tick. THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another options - with `dplyr`and `stringr`.

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(rep("BANK OF AMERICA", 2), "BANK OF HOPE", "T.D BANK"),
                 B = c("CHASE BANK", "BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.", "HOPE BANK", "CHASE BANK"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 


df <- df %>% 
  mutate(C = str_remove_all(B, c("BANK|OF|,")), #remove stopwords
         C = str_trim(C), #remove whitespace from start/end
         C = str_replace_all(C, "  ", ""), #remove double whitespaces
         C = str_replace_all(C, " ", "|")) %>% #replace whitespace with |
  mutate(D = as.numeric(str_detect(A, C))) %>% 
  select(A, B, D)

                A                     B D
1 BANK OF AMERICA            CHASE BANK 0
2 BANK OF AMERICA BANK OF AMERICA, N.A. 1
3    BANK OF HOPE             HOPE BANK 1
4        T.D BANK            CHASE BANK 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following base R option could help

```
df$C <- +do.call(
  function(...) mapply(function(...) any(!intersect(...) %in% c("BANK","OF")),...),
  Map(function(x) strsplit(x,"[[:punct:][:blank:]]",perl = TRUE), df, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
)
```

which gives

```
> df
                A                     B C
1 BANK OF AMERICA            CHASE BANK 0
2 BANK OF AMERICA BANK OF AMERICA, N.A. 1
3    BANK OF HOPE             HOPE BANK 1
4        T.D BANK            CHASE BANK 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a combination of regex and apply works well here.

```
> df <- data.frame(A = c('BANK OF AMERICA', 'BANK OF AMERICA', 'BANK OF HOPE', 'T.D BANK'),
                 B = c('CHASE BANK', 'BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.', 'HOPE BANK', 'CHASE BANK'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> f <- function(x) {
  left <- strsplit(x[1], "(BANK OF\\s|\\s|,|\\sBANK)")[[1]]
  right <- strsplit(x[2],  "(BANK OF\\s|\\s|,|\\sBANK)")[[1]]
  ans <- left %in% right
  as.integer(all(ans[!(left %in% "")]))
}

> df$C <- apply(df, 1, f)
> df
                A                     B C
1 BANK OF AMERICA            CHASE BANK 0
2 BANK OF AMERICA BANK OF AMERICA, N.A. 1
3    BANK OF HOPE             HOPE BANK 1
4        T.D BANK            CHASE BANK 0
```